# Find record in mongo $nin on array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a database (mongo) that stores posts and user separate. Within the posts schema I have an array. When a user marks a post as read, their user id is pushed into the array on the post schema. I'm then trying to display only the posts which their user id don't appear in the array.

Here is an example of my post structure.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("620eb60406b710c3ba2250f1"), "icon" : "fas fa-bullhorn", "title" : "Test Post", "scope" : true, "postedby" : "System", "postbody" : "Testing only content", "postcolour" : "orange", "posteddate" : "17/02/2022", "posthideuser" : [ "6205612355b2676a978b172b", "6203e917055a3558ffeb9fca" ] "__v" : 0 }
```

I tried using the following:

```
const posts = await Post.find({ posthideuser: { $nin: [user_id] } });
```

Which hasn't worked.

My Application is node, express/ejs. I will be happy to provide more information if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why in posthideuser there is an array inside another array? are you trying to match the value ending in 172b or 9fca? In fact, your example structure is wrong... there is a missing  `]`

Comment: Sorry I had shortend this as there is multiple users I didn't want to post to be so long. This is in fact correct on the live version.

Comment: It should work as @R2D2 answer... the only reason i think it couldnt  not be working is: Maybe you are comparing ObjectIds with strings...  you need to be sure you are comparing only ObjectIds or only strings

Comment: The problem was indeed with the storing of the user id within the array. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to work as expected:

```
 db.collection.find({
  posthideuser: {
    $nin: [
    "test2"
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V2HP8KUMtEN)

Comment: I've done the same within the terminal. With the same expected result. However when trying to run it via the application this doesn't seem to work correctly and all posts are return.

Comment: It appear to return the post, but not the result within the array. I feel the scope of the query i'm doing isn't actually what I need.

Comment: what is the user_id value?

Comment: thank you for your help I found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the structure as indicated.

```
await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { posthideuser: [res.locals.user_id] } });
```

should be:
await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { posthideuser: res.locals.user_id } });